# Unterschied: fremder Gedanke vs. fremdartiger Gedanke

Tags: difference, meaning

> 1. ein fremder Gedanke
> 2. ein fremdartiger Gedanke

Was ist der Unterschied?

Wenn ich mir die Beispiele auf Google anschaue, dann scheint die Bedeutung der Phrasen genau gegenläufig zur Bedeutung der einzelnen Wörter zu sein. Wörtlich bedeutet [fremd](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fremd) doch laut Duden, dass etwas nicht zu mir gehört, während [fremdartig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fremdartig) etwas bezeichnet, das zwar mein eigenes ist, aber wie fremd auf mich wirkt.

Den Beispielen der Suchergebnisse bei Google nach ist ein [fremder Gedanke](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ein%20fremder%20gedanke%22) aber eher eine neue, noch unvertraute Idee (die ich selbst habe), während ein [fremdartiger Gedanke](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ein%20fremder%20gedanke%22) ein Gedanke ist, der nicht im eigenen Denken seinen Ursprung hat sondern sozusagen von Dämonen dort hineingegeben wurde: "Der Bösewicht jedoch sagt, dies sei nur ein fremdartiger Gedanke, der aufgrund einer Sünde zu ihm gekommen ist ...".

Wie also würdet ihr die Bedeutung der beiden Phrasen – fremder Gedanke, fremdartiger Gedanke – fassen?

Wie z.B. unterscheiden sich die beiden folgenden Sätze:

> Ein fremder Gedanke befällt mich.
>
> Ein fremdartiger Gedanke befällt mich.

Comment: ...es gibt auch noch einen *befremdlichen* Gedanken ;)

Comment: @Takkat Das darfst du gerne in deine Antwort einbauen :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some overlap, of course. As I see it, the main difference between *fremd* and *fremdartig*, when put together like this, is that fremd means simply alien or foreign, in the sense of belonging to some external, third party, whereas fremdartig refers to the thought itself, judging it strange, different, outlandish. The same is true for *befremdend* or *befremdlich*, by the way, which also means strange or embarrassing as well.

A *fremder Gedanke* is simply not original, i.e. somebody else had it first.